I am getting an IllegalState Exception from MediaPlayer in a coroutine and do not understand why
My app is a simulator which shows a mouse running round the screen with occasional squeaks at random intervals to catch the cats awareness. I am gettng an IllegalState Exception in a singletrhread Coroutine. All the acivity for the MediaPlayer is in this thread so do not understand the error which occurs in the line where I am checking if the mediaplayer is still running the sound. It runs if I do not use coroutine but causes a sleep in the main thread which interferes with the update function and halts the mouse.
CoroutineScope(newSingleThreadContext("PlaySound")).launch{PlaySound(0)}

private fun PlaySound(sound: Int) {
    when(sound){
        0 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeak)
        1 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking1)
        2 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking2)
        3 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking3)
        4 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking4)
        5 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking5)
        6 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking6)
        7 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking7)
        8 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking8)
        9 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking9)
        10 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking10)
        11 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking10)
    }

    currentMediaPlayer.start()
    var metaD = ((currentMediaPlayer.duration.toLong()) * 0.8).toLong()
    Thread.sleep(metaD)
    if (currentMediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
        currentMediaPlayer.stop()
    }
    currentMediaPlayer.reset()
    currentMediaPlayer.release()
}

The error in the logcat is
E FATAL EXCEPTION: PlaySound Process: info.mstitservices.mouse4cat, PID: 11539 java.lang.IllegalStateException 
     at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method) at info.mstitservices.mouse4cat.Game.PlaySound(Game.kt:873) 
     at info.mstitservices.mouse4cat.Game.access$PlaySound(Game.kt:31) at info.mstitservices.mouse4cat.Game$MouseSqueaks$1.invokeSuspend(Game.kt:664) 
     at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) 
     at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462) 
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@9679fd3, java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@4038710[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]]

If I run the PlaySound as a normal function it works but hold up the main thread causing the mouse to stop moving.
Is there a different coroutine invokation I should use?

Possibly (but not definitely) related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19357036/208273

I modified my code based on a comment by Abhinav Upadhyay in the linked question posted by Ryan M.
The new code is here
    private fun PlaySound(sound: Int) {
    when(sound){
        0 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeak)
        1 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking1)
        2 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking2)
        3 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking3)
        4 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking4)
        5 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking5)
        6 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking6)
        7 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking7)
        8 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking8)
        9 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking9)
        10 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking10)
        11 -> currentMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(gameContext,R.raw.mouse_squeaking10)
    }

    currentMediaPlayer.start()
    var metaD = ((currentMediaPlayer.duration.toLong()) * 0.8).toLong()
    Thread.sleep(metaD)
    if (isPlaying(sound)) {
        currentMediaPlayer.stop()
    }
    playerReset(sound)
    playerRelease(sound)
}

fun isPlaying(sound: Int): Boolean {
    return try {
        currentMediaPlayer.isPlaying == true
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        println("Sound "+sound+" State Exception?: "+e.message)
        false
    }
}

fun playerReset(sound: Int) {
    try {
        currentMediaPlayer.reset()
    } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
        println("Sound "+sound+" Reset Exception?: "+e.message)
    }
}

fun playerRelease(sound: Int) {
    try {
        currentMediaPlayer.release()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Sound "+sound+" Release Exception?: "+e.message)
    }
}

This supplied me with information about which sound was in use at time an exception was raised and allows the app to continue running.
